# Reduction in adjective clause and OVS

Tags: adjective-phrases, participial-adjectives

*Backlash against a new Chinese television drama about its fight against Covid-19 underscores the challenges facing Beijing as it attempts to steer the narrative about its handling of the pandemic.* ( from a news from Blooomberg)

I have a question related to "challenges facing Beijing". Reduction in the adjective clauses, there is an obligation that subject is need to be before the relative pronoun, right ? So, how can "challenges facing Beijing" be possible ?
Such as like, Beijing facing challenges is acceptable but I didn't  understand how come "challenges facing" comes first.

If you help, I will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  To be honest, I don't fully understand the question, but I can say that there is no OVS here.  In a sentence like "Several challenges face Beijing", "several challenges" is the subject, Beijing the direct object.  There is no inversion.  At https://www.lexico.com/definition/face you can see definition 2.2, "(of a problem or difficult situation) present itself to and require action from (someone or something)".

Answer (score 1):

The word "facing" can be used either way.
"Beijing faces challenges steering the narrative...
or
"Challenges face Beijing in steering the narrative...

You may think of it as "challenges" and "Beijing", facing each other, compared to two individuals standing face-to-face. Each is facing the other.

Both meanings are shown here:
[Merriam-Webster "face"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/face)

> 5a : to recognize and deal with straightforwardly
> *face the facts*
> 6b: : to be a prospect or a source of concern for
> *the problems that face us*

Definition 5a has the people *facing* the problem.
Definition 6b has the problem *facing* the people.